# How SO decide which "top %" to show?

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-leagues

I've been active in SO for about 3 months and i was wondering why sometimes SO show those **top 5% this month** and others **top 2% this quarter**.

[image]

[image]

My questions are:

- How SO decide to show **monthly**, **quarterly**, etc. Which one is *better* to show? (if there is any)
- Are this *rank links* showed to every user with enough rep? If so, how much rep is "enough"?